# Appcelerator Titanium - a basic UI property works on android but not on iphone?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

everyone!

new to here

and been pondering about this myself for some times with no luck so i decided to make a post here

here is my problem

```
function refreshTableData(object){
var tableData=[];
for(var i=0;i<object.array.length;i++){
    var r=Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({height:'auto'/*,layout:'horizontal'*/});

    var nameLabel=Titanium.UI.createLabel({text:object.array[i].program_name,center:{x:'12%'}});
    var countLabel=Titanium.UI.createLabel({text:object.array[i].count,center:{x:'37%'}});
    var classLabel=Titanium.UI.createLabel({text:object.array[i].class_name,center:{x:'62%'}});
    var dateLabel=Titanium.UI.createLabel({text:object.array[i].date,center:{x:'87%'}});

    r.add(nameLabel);
    r.add(countLabel);
    r.add(classLabel);
    r.add(dateLabel);

    tableData.push(r);
}
tableView.setData(tableData);
}
```

the center property in the above code works fine on android

four labels positioned accordingly to my the value

but not on my iphone emulator

all four labels just stick to left side of the row covering each other

i checked appcelerator API the property is supported both in android and iphone

i don't know whats causing the problem

thank you in advance guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On default in iOS the labels are 100% wide. Therefore everything sticks to the left. By adding the property `width: "auto"` you should be fine. But it has to be set (on probably most UI elements in iOS the default is 100%).

Comment: may i ask why when i set a view's width or height to auto i get some warnings like this

[WARN] [object TiUITableViewRow] has an auto height value of 0, meaning this view may not be visible.

Comment: Because the TableViewRow does not have auto height as far as I know. That is fixed height